# Why I can't validate this JSON document containing an array that contains named object?

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to create a **JSON** document containing an array of objects where each object have a specific "name", so I created this JSON document:

```
{
    "forecast": [
        "morning": {
            "date": "01/10/2018",
            "min_temp": "12",
            "max_temp": "24",
            "humidity": "2",
            "wind_direction": "SO",
            "wind_force": "12",
            "status": "OK",
            "description": "sdfsdfsdf"
        },
        "afternoon": {
            "date": "01/10/2018",
            "min_temp": "",
            "max_temp": "",
            "humidity": "",
            "wind_direction": "",
            "wind_force": "",
            "status": "",
            "description": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see the **forecast** array contains 2 JSON object named **morning** and **afternoon**.

But in this way I obtain the following error message trying to validate this JSON document on the validator (https://jsonlint.com/), the obtained error is:

> Error: Parse error on line 3: ...cast": [     "morning": {            "date":
>   "01/1
>   ----------------------^ Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got ':'

Changing the previous JSON document in this format (basically removing the JSON objects name) it works fine and it is correctly validated:

```
{
    "forecast": [
        {
            "date": "01/10/2018",
            "min_temp": "12",
            "max_temp": "24",
            "humidity": "2",
            "wind_direction": "SO",
            "wind_force": "12",
            "status": "OK",
            "description": "sdfsdfsdf"
        },
        {
            "date": "01/10/2018",
            "min_temp": "",
            "max_temp": "",
            "humidity": "",
            "wind_direction": "",
            "wind_force": "",
            "status": "",
            "description": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Why the first version is not validated? Can I put the object name into an array in a JSON document? Or have I to add the **morning**, **afternoon** information as a value field of each object?

Comment: from which era a JS array can have properties like `morning` , `afternoon`. Look carefully its an array. Only Object can have properties not array.

Comment: You can have an array of objects, but there are no associative arrays in JS (or, if you like, there are — but they're objects). Your object array would just be indexed by the order in which the objects appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is not valid JSON. Array elements cannot have "a name" as this would just be an object...

```
{
    "forecast": {
        "morning": {
            "date": "01/10/2018",
            "min_temp": "12",
            "max_temp": "24",
            "humidity": "2",
            "wind_direction": "SO",
            "wind_force": "12",
            "status": "OK",
            "description": "sdfsdfsdf"
        },
        "afternoon": {
            "date": "01/10/2018",
            "min_temp": "",
            "max_temp": "",
            "humidity": "",
            "wind_direction": "",
            "wind_force": "",
            "status": "",
            "description": ""
        }
    }
}
```

The other way to do it would be put the name inside the object in the array.

```
{
    "forecast": [
        {
            "name": "morning",
            "date": "01/10/2018",
            "min_temp": "12",
            "max_temp": "24",
            "humidity": "2",
            "wind_direction": "SO",
            "wind_force": "12",
            "status": "OK",
            "description": "sdfsdfsdf"
        },
        {
            "name": "afternoon",
            "date": "01/10/2018",
            "min_temp": "",
            "max_temp": "",
            "humidity": "",
            "wind_direction": "",
            "wind_force": "",
            "status": "",
            "description": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the braces surrounding the array element:

```
{
    "forecast": [
      {  // HERE
        "morning": {
            "date": "01/10/2018",
            "min_temp": "12",
            "max_temp": "24",
            "humidity": "2",
            "wind_direction": "SO",
            "wind_force": "12",
            "status": "OK",
            "description": "sdfsdfsdf"
        },
        "afternoon": {
            "date": "01/10/2018",
            "min_temp": "",
            "max_temp": "",
            "humidity": "",
            "wind_direction": "",
            "wind_force": "",
            "status": "",
            "description": ""
        }
      }  // HERE
    ]
}
```